# Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot issue on a toshiba sattelite P 50 A 11 L

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had ubuntu 14.04 and windows 10 installed on my toshiba, everything was fine. But after a month, my computer starts only on widows, I tried everything I could but I cannot access the ubuntu installed on my PC. I have tried reinstalling everything, without success.

When I launched boot repair I got this : paste.ubuntu.com/14674884/

I really do not have any idea, every suggestion is welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Windows update or upgrade enabled hibernation and fast startup.
Boot into Windows system and disable hibernation and fast startup.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the old version of the Windows Control Panel.
Go to the Power Settings and uncheck fast startup.
Shutdown the computer completely (not restart).
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default OS.